# UIDatePicker UIScrollViewer

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have UIDatePicker inside a UIScrollViewer and I update my UITableView (reload) whenever I get a change from the date. But strangely, if I scroll datepicker very quickly it crashes and gives me the following errors?What could it be any idea? Here is the code where I get dateValue and set it to a instance variable (retained) startDate.

`[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance`

```
- (IBAction) getDateValue:(id) sender {
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"];

if(field == 2) {
    startDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [tableView reloadData];

}
else if(field == 3) {
    endDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
else {
}

[df release];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
```

That is not a retained instance variable; it's autoreleased. This means it will be reallocated by the next time the run loop spins, and is the source of your crash.

I would recommend setting the `startDate` and `endDate` variables via @property setters instead.

Comment: I did define it as property in my header file, but problem persists.

Comment: @user496398 you're accessing the ivar directly. Simply declaring the property does nothing if you never use it.

Comment: I guess I need to look at memory management more deeply. Thanks it works now!